# Clicking on elements with Apple Script

Tags: xcode, applescript

I have this use case

1. Open X code
2. Open Device and Simulators tab in X code
3. For each device in disconnected, just click on it, so it reconnects again.

I have written this much so far

```
tell application "Xcode" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Xcode"
    click menu item "Devices and Simulators" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell front window of (first application process whose frontmost is true)
        set uiElems to entire contents
    end tell
end tell
```

This activates X code and opens up Devices and Simulators tab and then prints the entire content. I am unable to figure out how to click on all the devices?

This is a picture where I am
[image]

The output I get from the screen in Apple Script is this

```
{splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", row 1 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", UI element "Disconnected" of row 1 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", static text "Disconnected" of UI element "Disconnected" of row 1 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", row 2 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", UI element "SEA C07DQLQGJG2X" of row 2 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", image 1 of UI element "SEA C07DQLQGJG2X" of row 2 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", static text "SEA C07DQLQGJG2X" of UI element "SEA C07DQLQGJG2X" of row 2 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", image 2 of UI element "SEA C07DQLQGJG2X" of row 2 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", row 3 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", UI element "PTS_Prod_iPadmini4_F9FVQ3W9GHKL" of row 3 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", image 1 of UI element "PTS_Prod_iPadmini4_F9FVQ3W9GHKL" of row 3 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", static text "PTS_Prod_iPadmini4_F9FVQ3W9GHKL" of UI element "PTS_Prod_iPadmini4_F9FVQ3W9GHKL" of row 3 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", image 2 of UI element "PTS_Prod_iPadmini4_F9FVQ3W9GHKL" of row 3 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", column 1 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", button 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", text field 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", button "toggle filter" of text field 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", checkbox "Devices" of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", checkbox "Simulators" of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", splitter 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", static text "SEA C07DQLQGJG2X" of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", static text "tvOS 13.4.8 (17M61)" of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", static text "Model: Apple TV (4th generation)" of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", static text "Capacity: 26.74 GB (25.75 GB available)" of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", static text "Serial Number: C07DQLQGJG2X" of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", static text "Identifier: " of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", static text "6ee6fcee1110eaefaed34bfb43edeb931543015a" of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", checkbox "Show as run destination" of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", button "Take Screenshot" of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", button "View Device Logs" of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", button "Open Console" of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", static text "ERRORS AND WARNINGS" of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", scroll area 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", table 1 of scroll area 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", UI element "SEA C07DQLQGJG2X is locked." of row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", image 1 of UI element "SEA C07DQLQGJG2X is locked." of row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", static text "To use SEA C07DQLQGJG2X with Xcode, unlock it." of UI element "SEA C07DQLQGJG2X is locked." of row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", static text "SEA C07DQLQGJG2X is locked." of UI element "SEA C07DQLQGJG2X is locked." of row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", column 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", static text "INSTALLED APPS" of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", scroll area 2 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", table 1 of scroll area 2 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", column 1 of table 1 of scroll area 2 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", column 2 of table 1 of scroll area 2 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", column 3 of table 1 of scroll area 2 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", group 1 of table 1 of scroll area 2 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", button "Name" of group 1 of table 1 of scroll area 2 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", button "Version" of group 1 of table 1 of scroll area 2 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", button "Identifier" of group 1 of table 1 of scroll area 2 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", menu button 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", button 4 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", button 5 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", static text "DEVICE CONDITIONS" of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", scroll area 3 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", static text "No Conditions Available" of scroll area 3 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", scroll bar 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", scroll bar 2 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", button 1 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", button 2 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events", button 3 of window "Devices" of application process "Xcode" of application "System Events"}
```

I have to click on these 2 elements towards the left - "SEA C07DQLQGJG2X", and "PTS_Prod_iPadmini4_F9FVQ3W9GHKL"

Comment: You need UIBrowser. https://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/

Comment: @matt Did not find it much useful. I downloaded free trial and generated this using the tool ```select static text "SEA C07DQLQGJG2X"  of UI element 1 of row 2 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Devices" 
```, but it fails on AppleScript compilation only with "A text can't go after this identitifer"

Comment: I tried changing from select to click and it has no effect.

Comment: It seems to me as if we can not click on static texts